# Unknown sensor value calibration

Tags: c, algorithm, avr, atmel

I have to create a sumo robot. I have a line sensor which cannot cross a red line nor a black line. The robot starts on a white surface. I don't know the values I get form the ADC. Is there a way to tell the robot not to cross a line?

I thought to store the average of the 3 first values and then compare them with the readings.

Here's my code

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000 // 1 Mhz
#endif


#include <avr/io.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
//The maximal possible delay is 262.14 ms / F_CPU in MHz.  = 262 ms = 0.262s
#include <stdlib.h>

/*-----#Functions#-----*/

/*-----#Motor#-----*/
void motors_init();
void M1_forward(unsigned char pwm);
void Moveforward(unsigned char pwm);
void Movebackward(unsigned char pwm);
void Moveleft(unsigned char pwm);
void Moveright(unsigned char pwm);

/*-----#ADC#-----*/
void InitADC();
uint16_t ReadADC(uint8_t ch);
uint16_t sensor_average(uint8_t ch);


/*-----#Other#-----*/
void delay_ms(unsigned int time_ms);



/*-----#Global Variables#-----*/
uint16_t valueAnalSensor1;
uint16_t valueAnalSensor2;
uint16_t linesensor;


int main()
{
    DDRD = 0xFF;         //PD as output
    PORTD= 0x00;         //keep all LEDs off
    motors_init();
    InitADC();

    linesensor = sensor_average(1);
    valueAnalSensor1 = sensor_average(2);
    valueAnalSensor2 = sensor_average(3);



            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(500);   //wait for half second
            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(500);   //wait for half second
            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(500);   //wait for half second
            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(500);   //wait for half second

            delay_ms(500);
            Moveforward(10);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            Movebackward(255);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            Moveleft(10);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            Moveright(2);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);
            delay_ms(500);

    while(1)
    {
            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(100);   //wait for half second
            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(100);   //wait for half second
            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(100);   //wait for half second
            PORTD ^= _BV(PD4);       //turn LED off
            delay_ms(100);   //wait for half second


        //adc_result=ReadADC(0);           // Read Analog value from channel-0
        Moveforward(255);

        //delay_ms(500);
        //Moveforward(255);  // Full speed

        /*
        */
        //check_line_sensor();
        //check_analog_sensor();

    }
}

void check_line_sensor()
{
    uint16_t currentValue;
    currentValue = ReadADC(1);

    if(currentValue < linesensor);
    //TODO: backup motors AND TURN AND move forward
}

void check_analog_sensor()
{
    uint16_t currentValue;
    currentValue = ReadADC(1);

    if(currentValue < valueAnalSensor1);
    {
        while(ReadADC(1) > linesensor)
        {
            Moveforward(255);
            delay_ms(5000);
        }
    }
}


uint16_t sensor_average(uint8_t ch)
{
    uint16_t adcvalue;
    adcvalue = ReadADC(ch);
    delay_ms(1000);
    adcvalue = adcvalue + ReadADC(ch);
    delay_ms(1000);
    adcvalue = adcvalue + ReadADC(ch);
    adcvalue = adcvalue/3;

    return adcvalue;
}


void motors_init()
{
    // configure for inverted PWM output on motor control pins:
    //  set OCxx on compare match, clear on timer overflow
        DDRD = 0xFF;         //PD as output
        PORTD= 0x00;         //keep all LEDs off


    TCCR2 |= (1 << COM21);
    // set none-inverting mode

    TCCR2 |= (1 << WGM21) | (1 << WGM20);
    // set fast PWM Mode

    //TCCR2 |= (1 << CS21); // No need for a prescalar
    // set prescaler to 8 and starts PWM



    // initialize all PWMs to 0% duty cycle (braking)
    OCR1A = OCR1B = 0;

}
// Motor Control Functions -- pwm is an 8-bit value
//  (i.e. ranges from 0 to 255)


void Moveforward(unsigned char pwm)
{
    PORTB|=((1<<PB2)|(1<<PB1));
    PORTD|=(1<<PD3);  //Set BIT PD3
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD2); //Clear BIT PD2
    PORTD|=(1<<PD1);  //Set BIT PD1
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD0); //Clear BIT PD0
    OCR1A = pwm;
    OCR1B = pwm;
}

void Movebackward(unsigned char pwm)
{
    PORTB|=((1<<PB2)|(1<<PB1));
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD3);
    PORTD|=(1<<PD2);
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD1);
    PORTD|=(1<<PD0);
    OCR1A = pwm;
    OCR1B = pwm;
}

void Moveleft(unsigned char pwm)
{
    PORTB|=((1<<PB2)|(1<<PB1));
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD3);
    PORTD|=(1<<PD2);
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD1);
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD0);
    OCR1A = pwm;
    OCR1B = pwm;
}

void Moveright(unsigned char pwm)
{
    PORTB|=((1<<PB2)|(1<<PB1));
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD3);
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD2);
    PORTD&=~(1<<PD1);
    PORTD|=(1<<PD0);
    OCR1A = pwm;
    OCR1B = pwm;
}




void InitADC()
{
    //TODO: RECHECK THIS!
    ADMUX=(0<<REFS1)|(1<<REFS0);                         // For Aref=internal;
    ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(0<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0); //Rrescalar div factor =8
}

uint16_t ReadADC(uint8_t ch)
{
    ch &= 0b00000111;
    ADMUX= (ADMUX & 0xF8)|ch;

    //Start Single conversion
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);

    while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC));

    return(ADC);
}

void delay_ms(unsigned int time_ms)
{

    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < time_ms; i++)
    _delay_ms(1);
}
```

Comment: A lot of questions... What's the ADC precision? White ADC value? Red ADC value? Black ADC value? You need to get a baseline.

Comment: That's the thing, I dont know the values.

The ADC is 8 bit precision.

Comment: I just know that the robot will start on a white surface. I thought about storing this value and using it as a compare.

Comment: Can you measure the values? Is white 0 and black 255, for example?

Comment: The sensor measures the value. It will be from 0 to 512.
But I dont know which one it will be.
I thought of this if(Readvalue > 0.9*initialValue || Readvalue < 0.9*initialValue ) {BACK UP because there is red of black tape}

Comment: Do you have the hardware that you can experiment with?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have not many options to interact with your hardware (like a display, keys, etc.) ... so if you are not able to measure the ADC value at the processor pin with a volt meter when the sensor is moved from white to black or red, you can write a small calibration routine that

- reads in the ADC value
- shifts the value through one of the LED's so you can read it out bit by bit
- blink another LED on-off in sync to provide you with a beat, so you don't miss the zero's ( alternatively you may output very small motor pulses to get audible feedback)
- while this is done, suspend all (real) motor actions

EDIT:
and there could probably be a data sheet of the sensor, too ?!?